# SvgPicture can't be assigned to ImageProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use svg image as background in Container and I use this package "flutter_svg" I can't found a Provider method to set it in decoration

```
    Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              width: 60,
              height: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: currentColor.medium,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/home.png'),
                ),
              ),
);
```

> The argument type 'SvgPicture' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

so I don't know how to use svg as ImageProvider here , any idea

Comment: Why don't you use another format?

Comment: @Guilherme because it's less size than png

Answer (score 10):

There are two options:

First one, write a function for that, as commented in `flutter_svg` package at [here](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/152#issuecomment-482017551):

```
final String rawSvg = '''<svg viewBox="...">...</svg>''';
final DrawableRoot svgRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(rawSvg, rawSvg);

final Picture picture = svgRoot.toPicture();
final Image image = await picture.toImage(width, height);
return RawImage(image, 1.0);
```

And second one, use another [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg_provider) on top of `svg_flutter` package:

```
import 'package:flutter_svg_provider/flutter_svg_provider.dart';

Image(
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
  image: Svg('assets/my_icon.svg'),
)
```

Comment: Hello. Can we set something like boxfit when using flutter_svg_provider as the image of BoxDecoration? Its default size is 100x100.

Comment: Hello @Omid Raha, can you please explain, in the first option, how we get from RawImage to something compatible with ImageProvider? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should add to your pubspec.yaml, flutter_svg_provider: ^1.0.0 instead of flutter_svg: ^1.0.0

Answer (score -1):

SvgPicture takes svg files as input.

Your code are trying to load png in SvgPicture.asset function.

A widget that will parse SVG data for rendering on screen.

```
image: SvgPicture.asset('assets/home.png'), // here
```

So you can use the PNG image as below

```
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/home.png')).image
```

Refactor your code:

> ```
> Container(
>   margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
>   width: 60,
>   height: 20,
>   decoration: BoxDecoration(
>     color: currentColor.medium,
>     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
>     image: DecorationImage(
>       image: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/home.png')).image,
>     ),
>   ),
> );
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Flutter developers have created one library you can find here 
`https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/06/flutter-draw-svg-vector-drawables.html`

Comment: I know that library I'm using it already but the problem is  I can't use it as ImageProvider