# I can't add an svg type image in a container

Tags: flutter

```
Container(
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: SvgPicture.asset(myImage)
    )
  )
)
```

Here is the error message: `The 'DecorationImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'`
thank you in advance

Comment: this is because `image:` property has a type of `ImageProvider<Object> ` but `SvgPicture.asset(myImage)` is a `Widget`

Comment: Ok. But how can I add my svg image ?

Comment: you need to write a custom `Decoration` class (for more info see how [BoxDecoration](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/18116933e7/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_decoration.dart#L75) is implemented)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217425/svgpicture-cant-be-assigned-to-imageprovider

Answer (score 0):

Import the package flutter_svg
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

add it like this ...

```
SvgPicture.asset(
  'assetLocation',
  
);
```